# Compare password encrypted with apache2 MD5, htpasswd

Tags: php, apache, encryption, apache2, md5

I tried to compare two passwords with the Crypt algorithm:

The first one is generated by my program with PHP (md5())

The second password is created with Apache 2(with option - m).

But I have a problem: when I compare the two passwords, with my code I obtain every time the same password (crypted). I noticed that for the same password if I repeat the process Apache 2 generates another encrypted password.

Example :

user = "user" password="password" ,

apache2 generates this line:

" user:$apr1$.1.Yc13v$uKn/tf7xbfDlo5qVpMoO/. " with MD5 algorythm.

And in my program my password is encrypted as "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99". And if I try to generate the same user and password with Apache 2 I have this line:

"user:$apr1$yppuymMI$wucIxLfRKyWyZitz690Td1 "

What should I do for comparisons for MD5?

Thank you

Comment: [MD5 is not secure enough for use as a password storage hash](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Rule_1:_Use_a_Modern_Hash_Algorithm)

Comment: What should I use as a secure algorithm ?

Comment: @Mis — There are three suggestions at the other end of that link.

Comment: These passwords are not being encrypted, they are being hashed. There's a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of which hashing algorithm you use, I suspect your original problem was with different salt values --

```
yppuymMI

.1.Yc13v
```

(Source:  [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/password_encryptions.html))